# Accurev: scripts to pull code from other streams

Tags: accurev

I have a core source of code that is shared in projects. I would like to have a script that, when the 'parent' has a workspace is created, that the children have their workspaces created as well.

This would help the developers not miss any references.

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: Solution:

I created a windows CL batch that

- checks if the folder exists on the file system, if not
- them call accurev mkws, followed by accurev pop.

It works fine

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: I have mixed windows CL command with the accurev ones.

Comment: Would you mind posting your solution as an answer and selecting it as the correct answer? It is the appropriate way to resolve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of the solution I came up with. It is missing items like, updating a dependency WS creation if it already exits . ... .

I created a bat file in the 'parent' stream. Then commands (in a bat file), are run to get the children.

example:

```
IF NOT EXIST [filesystem location for stream] 
(accurev mkws -w [stream name] -b [stream name] -l [location to put the stream]  accurev pop -O -R -L [location to put the stream]) 
else  @echo ~[stream name] already exists
```